# Cannot get joined teams using Graph for external users using mail identity

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am attempting to use "v1.0/me/joinedTeams" to get all the joined teams for the currently authenticated user in my asp.net service. This works fine for external accounts that use a Microsoft identity (have a live account) but the same call returns a 400 Bad Request when I attempt to use an external account that uses a mail identity (no live account). The request is the same regardless of external account type. The token generated when authenticating as the mail identity external user looks correct when I inspect it.

I have been able to implement a workaround where I instead use the SharePoint REST service to get the groupId for the team site the user is apart of and then use the Graph call "v1.0/teams/{groupId}" to get that team. However, I need to do this for all the teams the external user has access to which slows things down quiet a bit.

I am aware of what looks like a bug in Graph when trying to make any Graph calls with any external user type, described here: https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/1039. I have also implemented the workaround for this issue which requires first accessing each site the user has access to by making some arbitrary call using the REST service. Then any subsequent calls using Graph should work.  I do this for external accounts with a mail identity before trying to make the joinedTeams call but still run into the 400 response.

These workarounds will suffice in the short term but they increase my execution time significantly, especially when there is a large number of teams the external user is apart of. Any insight on a solution is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems like this is not available for external guest users. We will check and confirm you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/me/joinedTeams` is not available for personal Microsoft accounts. Se the table on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-joinedteams?view=graph-rest-1.0#permissions)